# Install from source successfully, but 'No module named tensorflow' under python

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed  Tensorflow 1.9.0  from source code.

1. I create new env use conda:

> conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7

2. I create **tensorflow-1.9.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl** file successfully in the dir: */tmp/tensorflow_pkg/*, following the tutorial on [official web](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).
3. I use **pip** to install the .whl file  in the tensorflow evn:

> source activate tensorflow
>
> pip install  /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.9.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl

4. I got the successful message:

> (tensorflow) usename@lab:$ pip install
>   /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.9.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
>   Processing
>   /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.9.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (3.6.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   astor>=0.6.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.6.2) Requirement already satisfied:
>   backports.weakref>=1.0rc1 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.0.post1) Requirement already satisfied:
>   setuptools<=39.1.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (39.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: wheel in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.31.1) Requirement already satisfied:
>   mock>=2.0.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (2.0.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   enum34>=1.1.6 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.1.6) Requirement already satisfied:
>   gast>=0.2.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.2.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   termcolor>=1.1.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.1.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   absl-py>=0.1.6 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.2.2) Requirement already satisfied:
>   six>=1.10.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.11.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.8.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   grpcio>=1.8.6 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.12.1) Requirement already satisfied:
>   numpy>=1.13.3 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.14.5) Requirement already satisfied:
>   funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.0.2) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (4.0.4) Requirement already
>   satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (1.5.0) Requirement
>   already satisfied: futures>=3.1.1; python_version < "3" in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (3.2.0) Requirement
>   already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (2.6.11) Requirement
>   already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.14.1) Requirement
>   already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc0) (0.9999999)
>   Installing collected packages: tensorflow Successfully installed
>   tensorflow-1.9.0rc0

5. but I got the Error : ** No module named tensorflow** :

> Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May  1 2018,
>   23:32:55) [GCC 7.2.0] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import tensorflow Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named tensorflow

6. **pip show tensorflow**

> (tensorflow) usename@lab:$ pip show  tensorflow Name:
>   tensorflow Version: 1.9.0rc0 Summary: TensorFlow is an open source
>   machine learning framework for everyone. Home-page:
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/ Author: Google Inc. Author-email:
>   opensource@google.com License: Apache 2.0 Location:
>   /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Requires: protobuf, astor, backports.weakref, setuptools, wheel, mock,
>   enum34, gast, termcolor, absl-py, six, tensorboard, grpcio, numpy
>   Required-by:

So, why can I import tensorflow ?
Thank you in advance!

Ubuntu 16.04
cuda:9.1
cudnn:7.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to install with pip 2.7? If you didn't specify it might have installed a for a newer version of python, thus causing the expected 2.7 module to not exist.

Comment: I use the default pip.  Also, I use the command: **pip --version**, and got the result:  **pip 10.0.1 from /home/csf/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)**.

Answer (score 0):

In anaconda you can use anaconda navigator to install packages. Just go to Environment and root and select "Not installed" on the drop down box. From there you can select tensorflow and install it. I suppose that judging by the date you probably don't need this any more but maybe someone else could use the info.